# Reverse direction of writing automatically with RTL script

Tags: macros, xetex, luatex, right-to-left

A new interesting feature with latest release of `babel` a lua algorithm which detect the beginning and the end of Arabic sentences and revers direction of writing without adding explicit markup (`\textdir TRT`)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[bidi=basic-r]{babel}
\babelprovide[import, main]{arabic}
\babelfont{rm}{Amiri}
\begin{document}
Example of latin text - مثال لنص عربي 
\end{document}
```

I have two questions

## First question

Can someone explain how this algorithm was built

## Second question

How to create a similaire effect with `xelatex` ( revers direction of writing without adding explicit markup )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The relevant code is `lua` code found in `babel-bidi-basic-r.lua` and `babel-bidi.lua`. As far as I know it uses the Unicode [bidi algorithm](https://unicode.org/reports/tr9/).

Since it involves `lua` code it can not work with `xetex` which only supports the `bidi=default` `babel` option (and a new `bidi=bidi` option, but I haven't tried this) and requires explicit text markup.

There is an (oldish) experimental package called [`unicode-bidi`](https://ctan.org/pkg/unicode-bidi) for `xelatex`. This package is not connected with `babel`. Instead it is set up for use with the [`xepersian`](https://ctan.org/pkg/xepersian) package. Even so it's output is not so reliable:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\usepackage{unicode-bidi}
\settextfont{Amiri}
\begin{document}
Example of latin text - مثال لنص عربي 
\end{document}
```

[image: output with xelatex]

Compare with the output from your MWE with `lualatex`:

[image: output with lualatex]

See also [Bidi algorithm and xelatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/403075/87678).